# Automatically catch all exceptions thrown by BlazeDS remoting methods?

Tags: java, exception, blazeds

Is there a way to automatically catch all (unchecked) exceptions thrown by BlazeDS remoting methods, without wrapping each one in a last-resort try/catch block? My code catches any checked exceptions as required, but I'd prefer that stray NullPointerExceptions, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions and the like don't end up being set to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use Spring-BlazeDs integration project. One of the benefits is the ExceptionTranslator mechanism which can solve your problem, I wrote an article [here](http://cornelcreanga.com/2010/05/java-exceptions-and-flex/).

If you cannot use Spring you can take a look in BlazeDS source code and add your own interceptor. The BlazeDS code is clean and not hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately our project is not using Spring, but I will do some more poking around in the BlazeDS source and see what I can find.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)), i guess it gives you just what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that, but I don't think it will work in my situation. All exceptions uncaught in my code will be caught by BlazeDS and won't make it up to that default handler. I'd like a way to catch them before Blaze gets them, or perhaps some sort of filter if BlazeDS supported it.

Comment: You might look what you can accomplish with Aspect oriented programming. (AspectJ for example). It is very powerfull, and let you do many things compile time or runtime.